# Is it idiomatic Rust to accept a Result<T, E> as a function argument?

Tags: error-handling, rust, idioms

Consider the following code:

```rust
fn foo(x: i32) -> Result<i32, Error> {
    //...
}

fn bar(x: Result<i32,Error>) -> Result<i32, Error> {
    //...
}

fn main() {
    let y = bar(foo(2)).unwrap();
}
```

Is this idiomatic, to pass the `Result` type around? Or should you handle the error or unwrap the result of `bar()` before passing the `i32` directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's quite unusual to accept a `Result` as an argument, except in general purpose libraries for dealing with `Result`s.

`Result` has [a lot of methods](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#methods) which help make working with it more ergonomic. For example, `and_then`, which chains a function call onto a previous result. Your example can be changed to:

```
fn foo(x: i32) -> Result<i32, Error> {
    //...
}

fn bar(x: i32) -> Result<i32, Error> {
    //...
}

fn main() {
    let y = foo(2).and_then(|value| bar(value)).unwrap();

    // or more concisely in this simple case:
    let y = foo(2).and_then(bar).unwrap();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't say I've seen a situation where it made much sense but without a clearer explanation as to why you'd do that it's difficult to help more.

Essentially, does `bar` have any use for an `Err()` input, or is it just going to pass that through directly? In the former case, then yes it might make sense for `bar` to take a `Result` -- though given you're asking the question that looks unlikely

However if `bar` starts with something along the lines of

```rust
fn bar(x: Result<i32, Error>) -> Result<i32, Error> {
    let y = x?;
    // work with an actual `i32` and potentially output an error as well
```

that is it has no actual use for an `Err`, then no, it's not idiomatic, the input is unnecessarily and uselessly complicated.

In this case what you'd want is:

```rust
fn bar(x: i32) -> Result<i32, Error> {
    //...
}

fn main() {
    let y = foo(2).and_then(bar).unwrap();
}
```